# How to extract information to Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

```
<input type="hidden" name="formid" class="Field FieldDescriptor" value="777">
```

I would like to return 777 as "formid" variable in Google Tag Manager. When I test it, it returns as undefined.
[image]

What do I need to do to have GTM pull "777" as the "formid" value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have `formid` as a data layer variable. To get it as a data layer variable, you first have to push it into the dataLayer array from the global scope.

But that's not what you want. Now, how do you get a formID value? depends on when you need it. The simplest way would be just pulling it through a JS variable that would look like so:

```js
function(){
    return document.querySelector('input[type="hidden"][name="formid"][class="Field FieldDescriptor"]').value;
}
```

Note that it depends on certain input attributes and their values. The selector may be adjusted depending to your needs, but that would be a separate issue.